# mvn scala:script -DscriptFile=scripts/PrintHello.scala --> Does scripts folder to be part of the project?

Tags: scala, maven

Maven Scala: I created a scala project using archetype:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:1.0-alpha-7:create \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=org.scala-tools.archetypes \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=scala-archetype-simple \
    -DarchetypeVersion=1.1 \
    -DremoteRepositories=http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases \
    -DgroupId=your.proj.gid -DartifactId=your-proj-id
```

Now, I want to run a script file using:

```
mvn scala:script as described here mvn scala:script \
    -DscriptFile=scripts/PrintHello.scala \
    http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/maven-scala-plugin/usage_script.html
```

Any idea where to put my .Scala file? what does "scripts/" exactly refer to?

thx

Answer (score 0):

scripts/ is a directory on the same level as your pom.xml. That is...

```
/myproject
  pom.xml
  /scripts
    hello.scala
```

So from same directory as pom.xml, try...

```
>mkdir scripts
>echo 'println("hello")' >> scripts/hello.scala
>mvn scala:script -DscriptFile=bob/hello.scala
```